# getting back the value of the variable within the success function

Tags: ajax

```
function check_timer(){
    //get product ids
    var product_ids= document.getElementsByClassName("product_id");
    //create for loop
    for(var i=0; i<product_ids.length; i++){
        var product_id= product_ids[i].innerHTML;

        $.ajax({
            //send product id to check
            url: "check_last_timer.php",
            type: "post",
            data: {product_id: product_id},
            success: function(end_time){
                //trying to get product_id here

                //$("#timer"+product_id).html(end_time);
            }
        })

    }

}
```

I am trying to get my product id within the success function. As you can see I have a for loop that sends product_id e.g, 1,2,3...10 to "check_last_timer.php" each time it runs. Problem is how can I get back 1,2,3...10 within the success function. Each time the for loop runs, I get the last product id which is 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a loop variable declared outside a closure from within that closure.

As you're using jQuery, use `.each`:

```
function check_timer() {
    $('.product_id').each(function() {
        var product_id = this.innerHTML;  // or $(this).html()
        $.ajax({
            //send product id to check
            url: "check_last_timer.php",
            type: "post",
            data: {product_id: product_id},
            success: function(end_time){
                $("#timer" + product_id).html(end_time);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: that's a great way to do that...I just learned a new lesson, thanks Alnitak

Comment: @Shades88 yes, it's a lot nicer (IMHO) than using an explicit additional closure

Comment: So that's how we use the .each function. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This is because AJAX call is as name suggests asynchronous. The for loop proceeds queuing up ajax calls, so you will get last id as 10 because for loop is too fast and ajax calls take time to complete.

What you can do is send product_id to request. get it back from server in success then do processing

Comment: Thanks for the information. I actually have it solved using the way you mentioned about.

Comment: really? that's great, glad to help. then how about accepting my answer? ;)